# Not displaying content by its URL string - absolute urls

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Serious amateur here when it comes to C#. In .net I'm using a line of code to hide elements that I dont want to appear on a particular URL (below)

```
        <% if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/level-1"))
           { %>

Content here

    <% } %>
```

How do I adjust the url string to hide elements on level-3 but not necessarily 2?...(below)

```
Contains("/level-1/.../level-3/")
```

I could just specify the absolute url for level-3 but there are hundreds of them, so looking for a way to exclude all urls under level-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To *always* hide content for any URL that has 3 levels, then the following will do the trick.

```
var uri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
var parts = uri.Split('/');

if (parts.Length < 6)
{
    // doesn't contain 3rd level
    // html here
}
```

Comment: I always want L3 to be hidden regardless of what its parent name was, something like the below...<% if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Contains("/.../.../..."))
           { %>

Comment: @TomRudge I've updated the code. That will get you what you need.

Comment: Thanks! Hard to explain but what happens when Level-3 is called "folder-3" or "tom rudge" e.g. /.../.../folder-3 - the name does not specifically have to be level-3 I literally mean level 3 in the url string - whatever url name is present.

Comment: @TomRudge ah, ok, it looked like exact strings in your sample. I've updated the code. You can `Split` on forward slash and then see if there is anything in the 3rd level (aka the 5th part)